# How to fetch GCP compute engine price details by applying parameters- OS, network, disc, memory?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have downloaded GCP price list from - [GCP pricing list JSON](https://cloudpricingcalculator.appspot.com/static/data/pricelist.json)

Also I tried GCP interactive pricing calculator from [GCP pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/)

Above pricing `JSON` will give the output in following format:

```
"CP-COMPUTEENGINE-VMIMAGE-F1-MICRO": {
      "us": 0.0076,
      "us-central1": 0.0076,
      "us-east1": 0.0076,
      "us-east4": 0.0086,
      "us-west1": 0.0076,
      "europe": 0.0086,
      "europe-west1": 0.0086,
      "europe-west2": 0.0096,
      "europe-west3": 0.0096,
      "europe-west4": 0.0084,
      "northamerica-northeast1": 0.0084,
      "asia": 0.0090,
      "asia-east": 0.0090,
      "asia-northeast": 0.0092,
      "asia-southeast": 0.0092,
      "australia-southeast1": 0.0106,
      "australia": 0.0106,
      "southamerica-east1": 0.0118,
      "asia-south1": 0.0091,
      "cores": "shared",
      "memory": "0.6",
      "gceu": "Shared CPU, not guaranteed",
      "maxNumberOfPd": 16,
      "maxPdSize": 64,
      "ssd": [0]
    },
```

In the above format, there is no information about operating system, network, disk, zone etc.

As per I know, compute engine price may varry if I select different operating systems(windows,RHEL,.. etc) and network, disk, etc.

**Is there any API available for fetching/calculating compute engine price based on parameters (operating system, network, disk, zone etc.) by applying different permutations like?**

- http://cloud.google.com/compute?os=rhel
- http://cloud.google.com/compute?os=rhel&memory=13gb&zone=east

Answer (score 0):

I'm working for Google Cloud Support.
At the moment there is no such API for this matter. I have opened a feature request for this and you can follow the request's progress in this public issue tracker url https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73713821